# Class Referencing with multiple instances accessing Custom Properties

Tags: c#

I have a condition where I have a user Click a button and it launches a Custom Control. The base control is a TabPage.

```
CustomControl1 cust = new CustomControl1();
```

I have properties in my CustomControl one is like so:

```
private string ButtonName = string.Empty;

public string buttonclicked
{
get { return ButtonName; }
}
```

Either I am just not thinking about this properly or I am missing something.

If I try to reference the control, I get the last controls value back and not the control that is being used. I have tried all sorts of things and just cant get the selected tab to return the value.

```
foreach(Tabpage page in this.TabControl1.TabPages)
{
if(page.name == this.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Name)
{
 MessageBox.Show(cust.buttonclicked);
}
}
```

I always get the last control added and not the one selected. Appreciate advice, thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're getting the button's name from `cust` but you name it `page`. Do `MessageBox.Show(page.buttonclicked)` and what happens? Or just grab it directly: `((CustomControl1) this.TabControl1.SelectedTab).buttonclicked`.

Comment: What does "launching a custom control" mean?

Comment: @Neil - page.buttonclicked is not visible for some reason.

Comment: @Groo - "launches a Custom Control" create a new instance of the same control.

Comment: Or specifically, creating a new instance of a custom control named `CustomControl1`, derived from `TabPage`, and also adding it to the `TabPages` collection of the parent `TabControl`? Also, `buttonclicked` is a bad name for a string property (it sounds like an event or an event handler), consider using a simpler name (`ButtonName`, `Title` or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you're referring to `cust` - but that's not your loop variable. Presumably, you overwrite `cust` when you create a new custom control.

If the controls are actually the tabs, you need to refer to the tab instead.. Something like:

```
var custPage = (CustomControl1)TabControl1.SelectedTab;
MessageBox.Show(custPage.buttonclicked);
```

Since `TabControl1.SelectedTab` is of type `TabPage`, but you know it's actually a subclass of `TabPage` called `CustomControl1`, you want to cast it to `CustomControl1` (that's what the `(CustomControl1)` accomplishes).

Then you can access the members you defined in `CustomControl1` - e.g. `buttonclicked`.

Comment: Yes have tried that, and I know it should work but this cast fails. I must have an issue in my code somewhere. I will mark as answer and I will check my code... Frustrating. inherits: public class CustomControl1: System.Windows.Forms.TabPage

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code where you're adding these custom control tabs to the tab control? Perhaps that's something to do with it.

Comment: Re-built the control and it is working now. I don't know what was the problem but its now resolved. Thanks